# docker and DNS issues

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install a docker repo on an Ubuntu server, but it seems Docker has issues with DNS.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
Unable to find image 'registry:2' locally
Pulling repository registry
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/registry/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no such host
```

However, all other applications work fine. I can also do a wget on index.docker.io, so no issues there.

I am using an internal DNS server, which is a Synology NAS device.

resolv.conf of the server:

```
nameserver 192.168.10.2
search internal.mydomain.com
```

my /etc/default/docker options:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--bip=192.168.11.0/24 --dns 192.168.10.2"
```

I am using 192.168.10.0/24 as my internal ip range. the .2 ip belongs to my NAS/DNS server.

Docker version:

```
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d
```

Anyone a clue?

Update: changing dns to Google solved the download issue, but now it gives an error afterwards:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 33757f59f942583ff949f421fb5c266e6d1c2b0fdc1363565e77febf44feb60f: invalid argument
```

Some additional info about my setup:

```
jeroen@docker01:~$ docker info
Containers: 3
Images: 22
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 28
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-32-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.955 GiB
Name: docker01
ID: X6JB:IH7Z:OK5O:II5I:OJ6V:OERE:IPEM:PN6S:HDDM:G2J7:HRB2:4ZKO
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: A few things to try: Add one of the IP addresses for index.docker.io to your /etc/hosts manually (use `dig +short index.docker.io` to find them) and see if docker can pull the image. The `--dns` option sets up `resolv.conf` inside the container, so shouldn't be related to the client attempting to pull the image. What happens if you set the host's `resolv.conf` to use another DNS server, like `8.8.8.8` - does it work then?

Comment: Changing to 8.8.8.8 works. Strange, maybe the DNS server included on my NAS has some quirks.

Comment: Encountered another issue. question updated.

Comment: Could you pull another one? ```docker run hello-world```

Comment: Same result: jeroen@docker01:~$ docker run hello-world
invalid argument
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container a0a32d129a8a3c2b056c3f951b159d80c1a65d84421c9e0ba3529646c0facd99: [8] System error: invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I notice that you have "--bip=192.168.11.0/24"

Try changing this to an actual IP address, rather than a subnet. For example, try "--bip=192.168.11.1/24".

You will have to stop docker, remove the docker0 bridge (ip link delete docker0) and then restart using the new bip option.